# how to show popup without opening new url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, push-notification, service-worker

I am working on pushnotification using Service worker .When I am using http site .It move to `https` url and show pop up.But most of website
show pop up without opening the `https` link .
could you please tell me how this achieve ?

example 
http://www.jagran.com/

http://www.airtel.in/postpaid
these url  show notification url without going to https url and it also has http domain.[image]

I try to use iframe but it gives error

**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed**

Comment: So make it a secure origin …

Comment: Service workers can only work through HTTPS connection. [See more here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers#you_need_https)